# Framework7 checkboxes not emitting click event on IOS or Android

Tags: html-framework-7

I am using Framework7 checkboxes in my React app. I have an `onClick` set up on my `<input type="checkbox">` that updates my app state every time a checkbox is checked. It works fine on desktop browsers but the `onClick` event doesn't register on mobile devices. Has anybody run into this issue with Framework7? See example code below (unnecessary code removed for brevity).

My input:

```
<label className="label-checkbox item-content">
  <input className="fileChkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
    <div className="item-media">
       <i className="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
    </div>
</label>
```

My `onClick` function (simplified):

```
handleChange() {
    let filesChecked = [];
    let fileInput = document.getElementsByClassName('fileChkBoxes');
    for (let i = 0; fileInput[i]; ++i) {
        if (fileInput[i].checked) {
            filesChecked.push(fileInput[i].value);
        }
    }
    ProjectActions.batchDelete(filesChecked);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, clicking on a Framework7 input[checkbox] does not fire onChange in iOS/Android. Instead, set onClick on the label and wait for F7 to change the form object before getting the form values. On desktop the onClick works on the input field,but the following changes to your code will make it work on both. You'll have to pass in your formId that contains the checkboxes and you could make this more general by making the checkbox group name a variable.

HTML:

```
<label className="label-checkbox item-content" onClick={() => this.handleChange(formId, 'chkName')}>
  <input className="fileChkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="chkName"/>
    <div className="item-media">
       <i className="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
    </div>
</label>
```

JS (ES6):

```
handleChange(formId, checkBoxName) {
    setTimeout( () => {
        var form = new Framework7().formToJSON('#' + formId);                
        if (form && form[checkBoxName] != null) ProjectActions.batchDelete(form[checkBoxName]);
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated compared to the other answer, of adding the no-fastclick attribute, which seems to solve the issue.  Also there's a bunch of unexplained code here, such as ProjectActions.batchDelete.  How is that necessary in solving the problem?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when using a checkbox with React. The onChange event wasn't firing. I had to add 'no-fastclick' class to the label attribute to make it work.

```
<label htmlFor={htmlID} className="label-checkbox item-content no-fastclick">
```

The solution here helped me: http://forum.framework7.io/#!/getting-started:checkbox-not-binding-to-ng

Comment: Using F7 in React I came across this issue again but on a different element. I was using Dropzone.js for file uploads and the file input click event wouldn't work. After several frustrating hours of debugging I remembered this post. I added `no-fastclick` as suggested and it works fine. This might be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem still exist and no solution found for my issue. I am using angularJs with framework7. The issue is that the scope model value would not reflect the checkbox checked state when framework changed the value.

The angularJS solution can be achieved by adding a onclick event that stops propagation to the framework handler. Then add a ng-click event to toggle the model's value. Viola! The angular scope reflects the correct value and the framework checkbox does too.

```
<label class="label-checkbox item-content" onclick="event.stopPropagation(); return false;" ng-click="models.tss[$index] = !models.tss[$index]">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="models.tss[$index]">
      <div class="item-media">
          <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="item-title">{{ key }}</div>
      </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Since I originally posted this question I've found the F7 checkboxes to act very inconsistently in my React application. It makes me suspect that it's the result of some conflict with certain libraries. I've moved away from using F7 checkboxes in my apps due to this.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you actually don't click on the checkbox. Just use `onChange` instead of `onClick` and this will be much more correct

Comment: Using `onChange` actually doesn't solve the problem in this case. Both the  `onChange` and `onClick` event are not fired on the Framework7 checkboxes in Android or IOS. I've tried both with no luck. The accepted answer above solved the problem for me though. Thanks for the great UI framework Vladimir.

Comment: Strange, checked again, works fine for me. Anyway, be careful with timeouts, it is hard to rely on them here

Comment: change does work but is not the ideal solution since the user cannot select the same value that is already selected (since the change event wont fire)

Comment: using a click handler on the container li of the checkbox did the trick for me, since now I can hadle a click on the same option that was already selected.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I was able to do is add a click handler for the li container element of the radio and a change handler for the input itself.

If another radio from the group is selected the change will be triggered and if the same is selected the click of the li will fire. Be careful with double event: one for the change and one for the click. In my case it was no problem since the click only closed the modal.